# C# Speech Recognition disable grammar

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm trying to use several grammars for a Speech Recognition in C# and I want to disable them in certain cases.

My problem is that if I disable them nothing changes, here's a part of my code:

```
recognizer.LoadGrammar(g_init);
recognizer.LoadGrammar(g_menu);
recognizer.LoadGrammar(g_timer);
recognizer.LoadGrammar(g_say);

recognizer.Grammars[recognizer.Grammars.IndexOf(g_menu)].Enabled = false;
recognizer.Grammars[recognizer.Grammars.IndexOf(g_timer)].Enabled = false;
recognizer.Grammars[recognizer.Grammars.IndexOf(g_say)].Enabled = false;
```

Here I want to disable the init grammar and enable the menu grammar

```
recognizer.Grammars[recognizer.Grammars.IndexOf(g_init)].Enabled = false;
recognizer.Grammars[recognizer.Grammars.IndexOf(g_menu)].Enabled = true;
```

I want to know how to disable grammars and enable them in a later stage

Answer (score 1):

[`Grammar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.grammar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) objects have an [`Enabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.grammar.enabled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property that you can manipulate directly.  However, you may also need to [synchronize the recognizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms554811%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) after updating the grammars.

So:

```
g_init.Enabled = false;
recognizer.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
```

Comment: I added the Update after disabling one of the grammas, but it's still not working, it remains in the first "state", in the first grammar

Comment: @JohnSmith you'll have to provide more detail, then.